# How to load an arraylist dynamically into android activity?

Tags: android

Hi
I have developed a Web service which returns an arryalist of object. I wanted to know how can I load this arraylist in my android activity?

Thanks,
Sneha

Comment: question needs to be more clear, can u eleborate your question or u can put some code?

Comment: I want to display that arrayList fetched from web service in my android activity. How do i do it? Do i have to store it somewhere?

Comment: in what type you getting the response either Json or Xml?

Comment: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/04/read-xml-resources-in-android-using.html or u can use SAX parser(which is good one)

Answer (score 0):

Try [ListView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html)

Comment: In List View I initialize the arraylist in r.array.arrayName. But if i use web service how do i do it?

Comment: Parse the returned XML with a SAXParser and let it populate an ArrayList. If this doesn't work for you and/or you want to store your received data persistently, you might want to write it into the SQLiteDatabase and use a SimpleCursorHandler for your ListView.